# Hide scrollbar when scrolling another element on the same page?

Tags: css

I currently have a custom scrollbar like below. My page has 5 scrollable elements. How do I only have one scrollbar show up when scrolling that element while hiding the rest?

```
/*custom scrollbar*/
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 8px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.1);
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track:window-inactive {
    background: transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
    background: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS property `overflow: auto`. This will only show the scrollbars when they're needed

Comment: I mean even when the content overflows, i want the scrollbar to not show up when scrolling another element.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide all scrollbars with:

```
body { overflow: hidden }
```

As you indicate 'auto' shows scrollbars if content overflows.

I have never tried it but it may be possible to use JavaScript to get closer to what you describe but I have serious doubts about the ergonomics of such a design.